# How to export an encrypted non-seedless electrum wallet into bitcoin-qt?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, electrum, seed

How to export an encrypted non-seedless electrum wallet into bitcoin-qt?

Is it even possible?

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from Electrum => Bitcoin core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43197/migrating-from-electrum-bitcoin-core)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import the addresses. See [electrum2core](https://electrum2core.github.io/).